# Tensorboad - add_summary makes my code crashes

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am very new to tensorflow, and I try to display my first tensorboard.

I downloaded and executed ok the board for the example given here
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html

Following the method, I have in my code:

```
weights_hidden = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([image_size * image_size, 1024]), name='weights_hidden')
_ = tf.histogram_summary('weights_hidden', weights_hidden)
```

and when I run the session

```
with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
  merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
  writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("/tmp/test", session.graph_def)
  tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
  for step in range(num_steps):
    summary_str, l, predictions = session.run(
      [optimizer, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)

    if (step % 500 == 0):
      writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
```

The process crashes with the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/Desktop/xxx/xxx.py", line 108, in <module>
    writer.add_summary(summary_str, step)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/summary_io.py", line 128, in add_summary
    event = event_pb2.Event(wall_time=time.time(), summary=summary)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 522, in init
    _ReraiseTypeErrorWithFieldName(message_descriptor.name, field_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 453, in _ReraiseTypeErrorWithFieldName
    six.reraise(type(exc), exc, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 520, in init
    copy.MergeFrom(new_val)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 1237, in MergeFrom
    "expected %s got %s." % (cls.__name__, type(msg).__name__))
TypeError: Parameter to MergeFrom() must be instance of same class: expected Summary got NoneType. for field Event.summary
```

What am I missing ? 
Any help/comment would be very welcome

Thank you very much for the help

K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write:

```
_, summary_str, l, predictions = session.run(
  [optimizer, merged, loss, train_prediction], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I added a 4th argument `merged` which corresponds to the summary you are trying to get (you were only getting the result of the optimization step).

Comment: Yessss!! it runs correctly again now  :) (although much slower but it makes sense) Thank you Olivier

Comment: If you have an idea why it is not visible on http://0.0.0.0:6006/#histograms I'm interested ;) it says " No histogram tags were found. " even after  relaunching tensorboard and running the code again

Comment: Is your tensorboard command okay? It should be `tensor board --logdir /tmp/test`
You can also check if everything works by printing your loss `l`

Comment: Nop, I have not space between tensor and board (I believe it is correct). I run `tensorboard --logdir=/temp/test` (the file is created in the folder when I run the code)

Comment: My bad it is `tensorboard` (it was my auto corrected). Check you have the same name "/tmp/test" in your command line and in your code.  
Do you succeed in printing the loss each step?

Comment: Yes it is the same /tmp/test in code and command line. And the printed output from the code run is working correctly : `Minibatch loss at step 0: 358.789734
Minibatch accuracy: 8.0%
Validation accuracy: 28.8%
Minibatch loss at step 500: 19.730721
Minibatch accuracy: 78.0%
Validation accuracy: 76.7%
Minibatch loss at step 1000: 33.377281
Minibatch accuracy: 60.0%` etc...

Comment: Try using Chrome.
If it doesn't work, you can try to add writer.flush() at the end of your loop.

Comment: same :( I ll create a new separate post for that issue -- thanks a lot anyway, at least now it runs ;)